# Erro ao tentar consumir um Web Service Axis

Tags: java, web-service

Quando tento consumir funcionalidades de um web service, a seguinte exceção ocorre:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Stream write error
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

Já pesquisei na internet mas não achei nada.

Comment: Se possível poste o código ou parte do código que gerou a exccessão.

Comment: O problema é que tem segredos de negócio que não posso expor, mas o que precisa exatamente? to achando que o axis2 não suporta

Answer (score 1):

Tateando no escuro, vejo as seguintes possibilidades:

1. Um erro "oculto" na exceção. Não há outras pilhas de exceção antes que possam dar pistas sobre a verdadeira causa do erro?
2. Bibliotecas incorretas. Algo comum com axis é faltar uma dependência ou ter um conflito de *classpath*, isto é, versão incorreta de uma biblioteca.
3. Problema no servidor relacionado à implementação ou configuração do webservice que acaba retornando algum dado corrompido ou inválido.
4. Versões incompatíveis do *stub* (*client*) e *skeleton* (*server*).
5. Verões incompatíveis do protocolo SOAP.

Sugestões para depuração:

1. Utilize o SoapUI para testar o serviço. Funciona? Verifique se o cliente está correto. Não funciona? Arrume o servidor.
2. Crie um *client* independente, isto é, um projeto simples e mínimo com um método `main` e somente as dependências necessárias. Isso ajudará você a isolar o problema.
3. Em último caso, crie um outro webservice fictício a partir do zero e veja se o problema se repete. Se continuar, poste esse código aqui para análise, incluindo as dependências usadas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, o erro foi encontrado utilizando um cliente independente apenas com o main e biblioteca Axis2, o Web Service está OK, pois já realizei o teste pelo SOAP UI. E tenho um outro Web Service que funciona normalmente utilizando o axis2. Não sei mais o que fazer, vc me recomenda outra tecnologia para consumir este serviço?

Comment: @diegosoaresub Entendo que seu client com a mesma configuração e mesmas dependências funciona em outra situação, então vou assumir que não é um problema desses. Restou verificar se a mensagem SOAP está sendo gerada corretamente. Use uma ferramenta de monitoramento de rede e veja o que está transitando de/para o servidor a partir do seu cliente independente. A requisição é coerente com o SoapUI? Você também pode tentar gerar novamente as classes a partir do WSDL do servidor, caso não o tenha feito.

Comment: as clases que utilizei foram geradas diretamente pelo WSDL, depurei a biblioteca do axis2, e vi que a mensagem está sendo enviada corretamente, já testei tb as versões 1.6.0 e 1.6.2. Não sei mais o que fazer

Comment: @diegosoaresub Pesquisando apenas por "Stream write error" no google, algumas respostas dizem que essa mensagem vem do sistema operacional por não conseguir gravar algum arquivo. Pode estar ocorrendo do axis estar tentando gravar um log e o disco estar cheio ou sem permissão, então a mensagem é encapsulada dessa forma e pode estar ocultando a mensagem original. Você não consegue depurar o webservice fazendo o deploy no seu ambiente, por exemplo?

Comment: Pelo modo debug consegui capturar a resposta SOAP, que é: 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAPENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body> 
  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
   <faultstring>Stream write error</faultstring>
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: @diegosoaresub Precisa olhar o log do servidor pra ver se tem alguma outra mensagem de erro.

Comment: Estou rodando no main, não no server. Logo não tenho log

Comment: @diegosoaresub Está rodando o client e o server no main?

Comment: Não tenho acesso ao server, é uma caixa preta para mim.

Comment: @diegosoaresub Já tentou pegar a mesma mensagem gerada pelo client e colar no SoapUI?

Comment: Sim, desisti.. estou usando JAX-WS e está dando certo.. Obrigado :)